# Handling OnLoad (Loaded) in Silverlight Using MVVM Model

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, onload

I am new to Silverlight (version 4) and MVVM, and I can't seem to figure out how to bind a command in  the XAML to my ViewModel for the "Loaded" event of a UserControl.  I can bind a command to a button like this...

```
<Button Command="{Binding ShowImageClick}" />
```

And it works fine.  But I have no idea how to do something similiar onload.  I tried this but it threw an exception saying "Failed to assign property"...

```
<UserControl Loaded="{Binding WindowLoad}">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach could be using [this code snippet](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2009/08/13/c-code-snippet-to-create-commands-with-attached-behaviors-using-prism/) I created to hook-up commands with events using [Attached Behaviors](http://blogs.southworks.net/jdominguez/2008/08/icommand-for-silverlight-with-attached-behaviors/).

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 2):

The Expression Blend Samples project on Codeplex may be helpful:

[Expression Blend Samples](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Behaviors%20and%20Effects&referringTitle=Documentation)

e.g.:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <si:InvokeDataCommand Command="{Binding Command}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of Damian's answer and would typically use that solution.

Another common practice is the [InvokeCommandAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724018%28Expression.40%29.aspx) or similar behavior in Blend.

Comment: If you're a fan of his answer, why didn't you upvote it?  That's how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is best practice or not, but simply having a constructor in the ViewModel class seems to work well enough for me...

```
namespace App.ViewModels
{
    public class Main : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public Main()
        {
            // Onload code here
        }
```

Comment: @HiTech Are you familiar with MVVM?  The code-behind for my XAML is bare.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Will delete comments shortly as adding no value.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that  can cause a memory leak and have reverted to old-school Loaded. To check this, add a finalizer to your user control/page and ensure it is called when you do a GC.Collect().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps its not the proper way but it works for me.

View:

```
<UserControl Tag="{Binding InitializeMyUserControl}">
```

View Model:

```
public object InitializeMyUserControl
{
    get
    {
        // do some initialization in here
        // bla bla bla
        .. 

        return null;
    }
}
```

when UserControl loads it will try to get the tag value. In there you can initialize things.